# VBScript Shell not Getting Updated File

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I'm working on a VBScript that will be called by other scripts which copies the clipboard contents and uses it as input for the parent script.  The script calls two batch files, copyClipboard.bat and copyToScripts.bat.  CopyClipboard.bat copies the clipboard to a text file called clip.txt.  CopyToScripts.bat copies clip.txt to whatever path is passed in as a parameter.  The logic I have is below.

```
dim shell
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")

shell.run "C:\Batch\copyClipboard.bat"
shell.run "C:\Batch\copyToScripts.bat C:\Users\kkulis\Desktop\input.txt"

set shell=nothing
```

It seems like this should work, but copyToScripts.bat always copies what the contents of clip.txt were before it was overwritten by copyClipboard.bat.  So, even though copyClipboard ran before copyToScripts, it's as if copyClipboard never ran.  If I run copyClipboard.bat and then copyToScripts.bat in the command line, it works fine.  I'm thinking that copyToScripts doesn't get an updated version of clip.txt.

I tried creating two different shell objects, but that didn't fix the problem.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your batch files are executed at the same time, not sequentially. object.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn]). Set bWaitOnReturn to true.

We have to see the batch files.

Here's how to get the clipboard in VBS.

From Filter.vbs

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout

Sub Clip
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    ie.Visible = 0
    'Have to navigate to a local file to put IE into Intranet Zone, else this will generate security dialog asking permission
    ie.Navigate2 FilterPath & "Filter.html"
    Do 
        wscript.sleep 100
    Loop until ie.document.readystate = "complete"  
    txt=ie.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData("TEXT")
    ie.quit
    If IsNull(txt) = true then 
        outp.writeline "No text on clipboard"
    else
        outp.writeline txt
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The first batch script already copies the clipboard to a text file so I don't need the logic for copying it.  The issue is that the second batch file doesn't get the updated contents for the input file.  It's as if the second script is reading on old version of clip.txt.

For example, if clip.txt contained "Hello1" before the script was run and my clipboard contained "Hello2", after running the script, my input file would contain "Hello1".  And if my clipboard contained "John" the next time the script was run, my input file would be "Hello2".  My scripts are always one clipboard copy behind.

Comment: Both your batch files are executed at the same time, not sequentially. `object.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])`. Set `bWaitOnReturn` to true. It not good programming practise to mix scripts like this. None of them are designed to work together.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That works well.  Are you saying it's bad practice to have scripts calling more scripts or that its bad practice to have different languages calling each other?